# how to access localhost website from another computer in local network

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

After modifying the both the file (**httpd-xamp.conf** & **httpd-vhosts.conf** ) I can't access my website either in my localhost nor other computer.
typing in the browser address bar:
**mydomain.local**

But it only works in localhost computer when we when we type "localhost/phpmyadmin/"

when I'd like to allow another computer in the same LAN to access the website. I've configured the other computer hosts file to contain line:
**192.168.1.180 mydomain.loca**l
where 192.168.1.180 is the XAMPP computer IP address. But after typing the http://mydomain.local on the other computer browser, after pressing enter, the address becomes: http://mydomain.local/dashboard and message appear "Object not found & error 404".

So far, I have done this:
   Changed c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xamp.conf file to contain this

Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.180
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

On my XAMPP computer, I have the following configuration in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

NameVirtualHost *:80

    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myphpapp"
    ServerName mydomain.local
    ServerAlias mydomain.local
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.local-access.log" combined

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

Comment: what do you have on `<VirtualHost` tag? it should be `<VirtualHost *:80>` as in listen on any IP address on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Is the redirection proper to your script or are you just redirect to your router administration panel?

By the way, if you want to do everything with ease, just take a look at [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), one little line in CLI will solve your problem and it will also make it available outside of your local network!